How to show opacity 1, when html tag come in viewport area by using useAnimate of framer motion?
I want to show some animation when an htm element comes into the view port area. For that I am using the useAnimate hook of framer motion. But it fires the same time before coming to viewport areas.
const Intro = () => {
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate();
  const isInView = useInView(scope);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInView) {
      animate("h4", { opacity: [0, 1] }, { delay: 2 });
    }
  }, [isInView]);

  return (
    <div className="intro">
      <div ref={scope} className="row">
        <h4 className="text-center mb-4 font-weight-bold">
          BOOK THEBANDWALA FOR YOUR SPECIAL EVENTS
        </h4>
        <p>
          We provide the trusted service, our service is value for money. Anyone
          can book online, we do not charge any extra amount by our customers.We
          provide quality service as per our rates and never compromise to our
          quality. Search and find best service as per your requirement, we have
          a wide range of rates and quality that will fit your specific need.
        </p>
  </div>

I have no ideas how to set it to show only when it comes into the view port area?

The animation will fire as soon as the referenced element comes into view, which in your case is the parent of h4. Have you tried referencing "h4" directly?

yes I have directly fired h4 but was not animating nd then I changed somecode to run and its now working.
